# Get a node list from an apply-templates

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, nlp

It's me again.
I'm working on an NLP project  and my task is oriented about syntactic dependencies between words in sentences. But here is my xml :

```
<trame>
<codage>utf-8</codage>
<delimiteur><![CDATA[. ,:;!?/_-"'()[]{}Â§0*><=+#]]></delimiteur>
<items>
<item type="forme" pos="1"><f>euh</f><c>I</c><l>euh</l><a>B</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>ROOT</a><a>ROOT</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>O</a><a>B</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>B</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>U</a><a>O</a><a>0</a><a>0</a><a>-</a><a>92.90196761259227</a><a>91.26525310558021</a><a>U</a><a>U_mm</a><a>mm</a><a>79.99999999999996</a><a>259.01900000000006</a><a>$L1</a><a>-</a><a>B</a><a>B_hl</a><a>hl</a><a>U</a><a>U_Hm</a><a>filled-pause_Hm</a><a>filled-pause</a><a>Hm</a><a>U</a><a>U_Hm</a><a>U_filled-pause_Hm</a><a>filled-pause</a><a>Hm</a><a>U</a><a>U_filled-pause</a><a>U_filled-pause_Hm</a><a>filled-pause</a><a>Hm</a><a>0.460299</a><a>0.540299</a><a>(IU:B)_(PER:B)_(PAQ:U)_(GR:U)</a><a>(ASNUC:U)_(PER:B)</a><a>(PRN:O)_(PER:B)</a><a>(PON:O)_(PAQ:U)_(PER:B)_(GR:U)</a></item>
<item type="delim" pos="2"><f> </f><c>BLANK</c><l>BLANK</l><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a></item>
<item type="forme" pos="3"><f>bon</f><c>I</c><l>bon</l><a>B</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>ROOT</a><a>ROOT</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>O</a><a>I</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>I</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>U</a><a>O</a><a>0</a><a>0</a><a>-</a><a>93.61142792134571</a><a>91.82168183237229</a><a>U</a><a>U_mmm2</a><a>mmm2</a><a>280.0</a><a>139.99999999999997</a><a>$L1</a><a>-</a><a>I</a><a>-</a><a>hl</a><a>B</a><a>B_mh</a><a>lone_mh</a><a>lone</a><a>mh</a><a>B</a><a>B_mh</a><a>B_strong_mh</a><a>strong</a><a>mh</a><a>B</a><a>B_weak</a><a>B_weak_mh</a><a>weak</a><a>mh</a><a>0.540299</a><a>0.820299</a><a>(IU:I)_(PER:I)_(PAQ:B)_(GR:B)</a><a>(ASNUC:U)_(PER:I)</a><a>(PRN:O)_(PER:I)</a><a>(PON:O)_(PAQ:B)_(PER:I)_(GR:B)</a></item>
<item type="delim" pos="4"><f> </f><c>BLANK</c><l>BLANK</l><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a></item>
<item type="forme" pos="5"><f>pour</f><c>Pre</c><l>pour</l><a>B</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>AD(33)</a><a>AD(33)</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>O</a><a>I</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>I</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>0</a><a>0</a><a>-</a><a>93.55803841320873</a><a>93.98225339281224</a><a>U</a><a>U_hh</a><a>hh</a><a>238.0380000000001</a><a>172.99049999999997</a><a>$L1</a><a>-</a><a>I</a><a>-</a><a>hl</a><a>I</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>lone</a><a>mh</a><a>I</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>strong</a><a>mh</a><a>L</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>weak</a><a>mh</a><a>0.820299</a><a>1.099946</a><a>(IU:I)_(PER:I)_(PAQ:I)_(GR:I)</a><a>(ASNUC:O)_(PER:I)</a><a>(PRN:O)_(PER:I)</a><a>(PON:O)_(PAQ:I)_(PER:I)_(GR:I)</a></item>
<item type="delim" pos="6"><f> </f><c>BLANK</c><l>BLANK</l><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a></item>
<item type="forme" pos="7"><f>aller</f><c>V</c><l>aller</l><a>B</a><a>infinitive</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>DEP(5)</a><a>DEP(5)</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>O</a><a>I</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>I</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>S</a><a>W</a><a>-</a><a>93.81598710004415</a><a>95.55844144923779</a><a>U</a><a>U_hh</a><a>hh</a><a>229.99999999999997</a><a>185.00000000000003</a><a>$L1</a><a>-</a><a>I</a><a>-</a><a>hl</a><a>L</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>lone</a><a>mh</a><a>L</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>strong</a><a>mh</a><a>U</a><a>U_strong</a><a>U_strong_hh</a><a>strong</a><a>hh</a><a>1.099946</a><a>1.390299</a><a>(IU:I)_(PER:I)_(PAQ:L)_(GR:L)</a><a>(ASNUC:O)_(PER:I)</a><a>(PRN:O)_(PER:I)</a><a>(PON:O)_(PAQ:L)_(PER:I)_(GR:L)</a></item>
<item type="delim" pos="8"><f> </f><c>BLANK</c><l>BLANK</l><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a></item>
<item type="forme" pos="9"><f>du</f><c>Pre+D</c><l>de+le</l><a>B</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>sg</a><a>masc</a><a>OBJ(7)</a><a>OBJ(7)</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>O</a><a>I</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>I</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>0</a><a>0</a><a>-</a><a>93.91472893724618</a><a>93.43828093467815</a><a>U</a><a>U_hm</a><a>hm</a><a>310.00000000000006</a><a>132.99049999999997</a><a>$L1</a><a>-</a><a>I</a><a>-</a><a>hl</a><a>B</a><a>B_hm</a><a>motherless_hm</a><a>motherless</a><a>hm</a><a>B</a><a>B_hm</a><a>B_weak_hm</a><a>weak</a><a>hm</a><a>U</a><a>U_weak</a><a>U_weak_hm</a><a>weak</a><a>hm</a><a>1.390299</a><a>1.700299</a><a>(IU:I)_(PER:I)_(PAQ:B)_(GR:B)</a><a>(ASNUC:O)_(PER:I)</a><a>(PRN:O)_(PER:I)</a><a>(PON:O)_(PAQ:B)_(PER:I)_(GR:B)</a></item>
<item type="delim" pos="10"><f> </f><c>BLANK</c><l>BLANK</l><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a></item>
<item type="forme" pos="11"><f>CRDT</f><c>N</c><l>CRDT</l><a>B</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>sg</a><a>masc</a><a>DEP(9)</a><a>DEP(9)</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>O</a><a>I</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>I</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>W</a><a>0</a><a>-</a><a>89.88396668576091</a><a>92.21161134439662</a><a>U</a><a>U_hm</a><a>hm</a><a>482.86399999999975</a><a>230.9190000000001</a><a>$L1</a><a>-</a><a>I</a><a>-</a><a>hl</a><a>L</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>motherless</a><a>hm</a><a>L</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>weak</a><a>hm</a><a>U</a><a>U_weak</a><a>U_weak_mm</a><a>weak</a><a>mm</a><a>1.700299</a><a>2.513163</a><a>(IU:I)_(PER:I)_(PAQ:L)_(GR:L)</a><a>(ASNUC:O)_(PER:I)</a><a>(PRN:O)_(PER:I)</a><a>(PON:O)_(PAQ:L)_(PER:I)_(GR:L)</a></item>
<item type="delim" pos="12"><f> </f><c>BLANK</c><l>BLANK</l><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a></item>
<item type="forme" pos="13"><f>à</f><c>Pre</c><l>à</l><a>B</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>OBL(7)</a><a>OBL(7)</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>O</a><a>I</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>I</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>0</a><a>0</a><a>H</a><a>90.26366309887754</a><a>88.57247375870008</a><a>U</a><a>U_ml</a><a>ml</a><a>340.0000000000003</a><a>343.1742499999999</a><a>$L1</a><a>-</a><a>I</a><a>-</a><a>hl</a><a>B</a><a>B_mHl2</a><a>tail_mHl2</a><a>tail</a><a>mHl2</a><a>B</a><a>B_mHl2</a><a>B_tail_mHl2</a><a>tail</a><a>mHl2</a><a>B</a><a>B_strong</a><a>B_strong_mHl2</a><a>strong</a><a>mHl2</a><a>2.583163</a><a>2.923163</a><a>(IU:I)_(PER:I)_(PAQ:B)_(GR:B)</a><a>(ASNUC:O)_(PER:I)</a><a>(PRN:O)_(PER:I)</a><a>(PON:O)_(PAQ:B)_(PER:I)_(GR:B)</a></item>
<item type="delim" pos="14"><f> </f><c>BLANK</c><l>BLANK</l><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a></item>
<item type="forme" pos="15"><f>la</f><c>D</c><l>le</l><a>B</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>sg</a><a>fem</a><a>DEP(17)</a><a>DEP(17)</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>O</a><a>I</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>I</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>0</a><a>0</a><a>H</a><a>92.07666113239492</a><a>86.20573686283727</a><a>U</a><a>U_ll</a><a>ll</a><a>273.67600000000004</a><a>396.37325</a><a>$L1</a><a>-</a><a>I</a><a>-</a><a>hl</a><a>I</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>tail</a><a>mHl2</a><a>I</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>tail</a><a>mHl2</a><a>L</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>strong</a><a>mHl2</a><a>2.923163</a><a>3.196839</a><a>(IU:I)_(PER:I)_(PAQ:I)_(GR:I)</a><a>(ASNUC:O)_(PER:I)</a><a>(PRN:O)_(PER:I)</a><a>(PON:O)_(PAQ:I)_(PER:I)_(GR:I)</a></item>
<item type="delim" pos="16"><f> </f><c>BLANK</c><l>BLANK</l><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a></item>
<item type="forme" pos="17"><f>gare</f><c>N</c><l>gare</l><a>B</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>sg</a><a>fem</a><a>DEP(13)</a><a>DEP(13)</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>O</a><a>I</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>I</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>0</a><a>S</a><a>-</a><a>88.17122257833398</a><a>97.38585113265228</a><a>U</a><a>U_HH</a><a>HH</a><a>346.4720000000003</a><a>344.91649999999987</a><a>$L1</a><a>0.237114</a><a>I</a><a>-</a><a>hl</a><a>L</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>tail</a><a>mHl2</a><a>L</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>tail</a><a>mHl2</a><a>U</a><a>U_tail</a><a>U_tail_HH</a><a>tail</a><a>HH</a><a>3.196839</a><a>3.959468</a><a>(IU:I)_(PER:I)_(PAQ:L)_(GR:L)</a><a>(ASNUC:O)_(PER:I)</a><a>(PRN:O)_(PER:I)</a><a>(PON:O)_(PAQ:L)_(PER:I)_(GR:L)</a></item>
<item type="delim" pos="18"><f> </f><c>BLANK</c><l>BLANK</l><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a></item>
<item type="forme" pos="19"><f>euh</f><c>I</c><l>euh</l><a>B</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>ROOT</a><a>ROOT</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>O</a><a>I</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>I</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>U</a><a>O</a><a>0</a><a>_</a><a>H</a><a>86.44444171734648</a><a>87.63023960575637</a><a>U</a><a>U_ml</a><a>ml</a><a>309.9999999999996</a><a>171.13449999999997</a><a>$L1</a><a>-</a><a>I</a><a>-</a><a>hl</a><a>U</a><a>U_ml</a><a>filled-pause_ml</a><a>filled-pause</a><a>ml</a><a>U</a><a>U_ml</a><a>U_filled-pause_ml</a><a>filled-pause</a><a>ml</a><a>U</a><a>U_filled-pause</a><a>U_filled-pause_ml</a><a>filled-pause</a><a>ml</a><a>4.196582</a><a>4.506582</a><a>(IU:I)_(PER:I)_(PAQ:U)_(GR:U)</a><a>(ASNUC:U)_(PER:I)</a><a>(PRN:O)_(PER:I)</a><a>(PON:O)_(PAQ:U)_(PER:I)_(GR:U)</a></item>
<item type="delim" pos="20"><f> </f><c>BLANK</c><l>BLANK</l><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a></item>
<item type="forme" pos="21"><f>de</f><c>Pre</c><l>de</l><a>B</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>DEP(17)</a><a>DEP(17)</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>O</a><a>I</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>I</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>0</a><a>0</a><a>-</a><a>88.80414647402179</a><a>86.72856086599734</a><a>U</a><a>U_ll</a><a>ll</a><a>150.00000000000034</a><a>257.940333333333</a><a>$L1</a><a>-</a><a>I</a><a>-</a><a>hl</a><a>B</a><a>B_lhH2</a><a>lone-dis-strong_lhH2</a><a>lone-dis-strong</a><a>lhH2</a><a>B</a><a>B_lhH2</a><a>B_dis-strong_lhH2</a><a>dis-strong</a><a>lhH2</a><a>U</a><a>U_strong</a><a>U_strong_lH</a><a>strong</a><a>lH</a><a>4.506582</a><a>4.656582</a><a>(IU:I)_(PER:I)_(PAQ:B)_(GR:B)</a><a>(ASNUC:O)_(PER:I)</a><a>(PRN:O)_(PER:I)</a><a>(PON:O)_(PAQ:B)_(PER:I)_(GR:B)</a></item>
<item type="delim" pos="22"><f> </f><c>BLANK</c><l>BLANK</l><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a></item>
<item type="forme" pos="23"><f>Grenoble</f><c>N</c><l>Grenoble</l><a>B</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>sg</a><a>masc-fem</a><a>DEP(21)</a><a>DEP(21)</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>O</a><a>I</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>L</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>0</a><a>0</a><a>-</a><a>90.53937299589111</a><a>97.37944865527233</a><a>U</a><a>U_Hh</a><a>Hh</a><a>307.07300000000083</a><a>515.0497499999998</a><a>$L1</a><a>-</a><a>I</a><a>-</a><a>hl</a><a>I</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>lone-dis-strong</a><a>lhH2</a><a>I</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>dis-strong</a><a>lhH2</a><a>B</a><a>B_dis-strong</a><a>B_dis-strong_Hh</a><a>dis-strong</a><a>Hh</a><a>4.656582</a><a>5.427476</a><a>(IU:I)_(PER:I)_(PAQ:I)_(GR:I)</a><a>(ASNUC:O)_(PER:I)</a><a>(PRN:O)_(PER:I)</a><a>(PON:O)_(PAQ:I)_(PER:I)_(GR:I)</a></item>
<item type="delim" pos="24"><f> </f><c>BLANK</c><l>BLANK</l><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a></item>
<item type="forme" pos="25"><f>je</f><c>Cl</c><l>je</l><a>B</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>1</a><a>sg</a><a>-</a><a>PARA_DISFL(31)</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>PARA_DISFL(31)</a><a>SUB_INHERITED(33)</a><a>-</a><a>U</a><a>I</a><a>B</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>S</a><a>S</a><a>H</a><a>92.99257118776505</a><a>93.45817303640241</a><a>U</a><a>U_hh</a><a>hh</a><a>524.4369999999998</a><a>474.6527500000002</a><a>$L1</a><a>-</a><a>I</a><a>-</a><a>hl</a><a>L</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>lone-dis-strong</a><a>lhH2</a><a>L</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>dis-strong</a><a>lhH2</a><a>L</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>dis-strong</a><a>Hh</a><a>5.427476</a><a>5.951913</a><a>(IU:I)_(PER:I)_(PAQ:L)_(GR:L)</a><a>(ASNUC:O)_(PER:I)</a><a>(PRN:O)_(PER:I)</a><a>(PON:O)_(PAQ:L)_(PER:I)_(GR:L)</a></item>
<item type="delim" pos="26"><f> </f><c>BLANK</c><l>BLANK</l><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a></item>
<item type="forme" pos="27"><f>euh</f><c>I</c><l>euh</l><a>B</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>ROOT</a><a>ROOT</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>B</a><a>I</a><a>I</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>U</a><a>O</a><a>0</a><a>0</a><a>H</a><a>94.4949160993508</a><a>89.91711913085308</a><a>U</a><a>U_hl</a><a>hl</a><a>1071.9409999999998</a><a>312.52675000000016</a><a>$L1</a><a>-</a><a>I</a><a>-</a><a>hl</a><a>B</a><a>B_hml2</a><a>lone_hml2</a><a>lone</a><a>hml2</a><a>B</a><a>B_hml2</a><a>B_strong_hml2</a><a>strong</a><a>hml2</a><a>B</a><a>B_strong</a><a>B_strong_hml2</a><a>strong</a><a>hml2</a><a>5.951913</a><a>7.023854</a><a>(IU:I)_(PER:I)_(PAQ:B)_(GR:B)</a><a>(ASNUC:U)_(PER:I)</a><a>(PRN:O)_(PER:I)</a><a>(PON:O)_(PAQ:B)_(PER:I)_(GR:B)</a></item>
<item type="delim" pos="28"><f> </f><c>BLANK</c><l>BLANK</l><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a></item>
<item type="forme" pos="29"><f>ben</f><c>I</c><l>ben</l><a>B</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>ROOT</a><a>ROOT</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>I</a><a>I</a><a>I</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>U</a><a>O</a><a>0</a><a>0</a><a>-</a><a>93.7920165269197</a><a>92.05183971732146</a><a>U</a><a>U_mm</a><a>mm</a><a>248.0450000000003</a><a>484.5832499999998</a><a>$L1</a><a>-</a><a>I</a><a>-</a><a>hl</a><a>I</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>lone</a><a>hml2</a><a>I</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>strong</a><a>hml2</a><a>I</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>strong</a><a>hml2</a><a>7.023854</a><a>7.271899</a><a>(IU:I)_(PER:I)_(PAQ:I)_(GR:I)</a><a>(ASNUC:U)_(PER:I)</a><a>(PRN:O)_(PER:I)</a><a>(PON:O)_(PAQ:I)_(PER:I)_(GR:I)</a></item>
<item type="delim" pos="30"><f> </f><c>BLANK</c><l>BLANK</l><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a></item>
<item type="forme" pos="31"><f>je</f><c>Cl</c><l>je</l><a>B</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>1</a><a>sg</a><a>-</a><a>SUB(33)</a><a>SUB(33)</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>L</a><a>I</a><a>I</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>0</a><a>0</a><a>-</a><a>92.89293289439333</a><a>95.09020298840696</a><a>U</a><a>U_mhH2</a><a>mhH2</a><a>170.55199999999982</a><a>402.84725</a><a>$L1</a><a>-</a><a>I</a><a>-</a><a>hl</a><a>I</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>lone</a><a>hml2</a><a>I</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>strong</a><a>hml2</a><a>I</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>strong</a><a>hml2</a><a>7.271899</a><a>7.442451</a><a>(IU:I)_(PER:I)_(PAQ:I)_(GR:I)</a><a>(ASNUC:O)_(PER:I)</a><a>(PRN:O)_(PER:I)</a><a>(PON:O)_(PAQ:I)_(PER:I)_(GR:I)</a></item>
<item type="delim" pos="32"><f> </f><c>BLANK</c><l>BLANK</l><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a></item>
<item type="forme" pos="33"><f>sors</f><c>V</c><l>sortir</l><a>B</a><a>indicative</a><a>present</a><a>1</a><a>sg</a><a>-</a><a>ROOT</a><a>ROOT</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>O</a><a>I</a><a>I</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>S</a><a>S</a><a>-</a><a>92.82106348940435</a><a>96.70257095201634</a><a>U</a><a>U_Hm</a><a>Hm</a><a>171.40299999999974</a><a>172.14925000000014</a><a>$L1</a><a>-</a><a>I</a><a>-</a><a>hl</a><a>L</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>lone</a><a>hml2</a><a>L</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>strong</a><a>hml2</a><a>L</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>strong</a><a>hml2</a><a>7.442451</a><a>7.613854</a><a>(IU:I)_(PER:I)_(PAQ:L)_(GR:L)</a><a>(ASNUC:O)_(PER:I)</a><a>(PRN:O)_(PER:I)</a><a>(PON:O)_(PAQ:L)_(PER:I)_(GR:L)</a></item>
```

I need to extract two elements. They are both nodes item. As you can see on the xml, there is in a[8] for each item his parts of speech and a number which match with the governor of this word (attribute @pos from item). So i need to get all items with a[8] = SUB and extract the number to find the governors of each one SUB. Thus, i'll have the dependent word and his governor.
Example: in the sample, 'je' (item/@pos=31) have a a[8] = SUB(33) so himself, the dependent has as governor the item/@=33 so 'sors'. So i need the grab these two item nodes and for all the file.
But the problem is not here. My template that matches with items node needs to return values of these two item nodes and furthermore it's gonna be a list. Here is my code. It's pretty simple :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0"
    xmlns:saxon="http://saxon.sf.net/" extension-element-prefixes="saxon"
    xmlns:str="http://exslt.org/strings" exclude-result-prefixes="saxon str">
    <xsl:output method="text" encoding="utf-8"/>
    <xsl:variable name="count" saxon:assignable="yes" select="0"/>
    
    <xsl:template match="/">
        
        <xsl:variable name="items" as="document-node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates/> 
        </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:value-of select="$items"/>
        
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="items">
        
        <xsl:for-each select="//item[@type='forme'][contains(a[7], 'SUB')]">       
        <xsl:variable name="gouv_pos" select='replace(a[8], "SUB\((\d+)\)", "$1")'/>
        <xsl:variable name="gouv" select="//item[@pos=number($gouv_pos)]"/>
            <xsl:variable name="dep" select="current()"/>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="number($gouv_pos) > $dep/@pos">
                    <xsl:value-of select="$dep"/>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$gouv"/>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$gouv"/>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$dep"/>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:for-each> 
        
        
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="item">
        
    </xsl:template>
          
           
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I want to have in my variable items in template matching root, the list of nodes item grouped by two (the governor and the dependent). And this variable must be iterable. I don't know if it's possible but when i try to get the values with xsl:copy, it doesn't work.My war $items stays empty.

```
<xsl:variable name="items" as="document-node()">
<xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates/> 
</xsl:copy>
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:value-of select="$items"/>
```

My <xsl:value-of select="$items"/> is empty whereas i want a list of nodes item. How to do that ? And how to connect these two item nodes (dependent and governor) ?
With this problem managed, it's gonna be easier for me to do the task.
Thx for your help.

Comment: What kind of nodes (element nodes, comment nodes, text nodes) do you expect to have inside of your document node? As long as you use xsl:value-of you do not create anything but text nodes and adjacent text nodes are always merged. In an earlier answer to a previous, similar question someone showed you an example to create element nodes, for instance.

Comment: element nodes. i'll have to access to child nodes, attributes etc...

Comment: Well, then see the answer to your previous question, inside your template or for-each you need to create elements, either as literal result element or with `xsl:copy` or with `xsl:element`, just constructing nothing text nodes with `xsl:value-of` doesn't give you any XML structure with elements.